# marker clusterer - merging markers info window content

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

Does any one have a clue how to add an info windows to the cluster markers, containing the merged markers info window content?

This is an of the default marker clusterer behaviour: 
http://www.psop.fr/MAP_Population_Google.php

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should listen to the clusterclick event on the markercluster. The object that is passed into the event contains an array of markers that are in the cluster and the position of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
    markers = cluster.getMarkers();
    info = "";
    $.each(markers, function(x, marker) {
        if(me.infowindows[marker.__gm_id]){
        info = info + "<br/>" + me.infowindows[marker.__gm_id].content;
            }
    });
```

.....
something like that works, you get the markers associated with the clusterclick. and then loop through the infowindows, i'm not sure how yours is set up. but the above code should make sense.

you also need to disable the zoom on click as the clusters get re-drawn for each zoom.

Answer (score -1):

```
var contentString = 'This is an example';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```